# Best practise of inheritance model from parent asp.net page with examples

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm new in asp.net. How to pass model from Main page and work with it in my partialview. Can somone show me how to do it with examples and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can render PartialView like this example with passing model as a parameter.

```
@Html.Partial("YourPartialView.cshtml", model)
```

In your PartialView (YourPartialView.cshtml) you should define your model for the PartialView like this

```
@model ClassForYourModel
```

From now, you can use your models attributes as follows.

```
@model.Attribute1 
@model.Attribute2
```

[Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698246/ASP-NET-MVC-Special-Views-Partial-View-and-Layout)